# using statement with fluent api will not call dispose if throw occurs in fluent method chain

Tags: c#, fluent, using-statement

When combining a using statement with a fluent api that can potentially throw, the lowered code will never call dispose correctly.

If I have the following class that exposes a fluent interface:

```
public class Wrapper : IDisposable
{   
    private bool _isAdded;
    
    public Wrapper Add()
    {
        _isAdded = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose() => Console.WriteLine("dispose called");

    public Wrapper ThrowIfAdded() => _isAdded ? throw new Exception() : this;
}
```

and I call it with the following:

```
using var willNotDispose = new Wrapper().Add().ThrowIfAdded();
```

the lowered code will result in the Dispose call occurring *after* the fluent method chain is completed.

```
Wrapper willNotDispose = new Wrapper().Add().ThrowIfAdded();
try
{
}
finally
{
    if (willNotDispose != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)willNotDispose).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the call to `.ThrowIfAdded()` is done outside of the initial `using` declaration,

```
using var willDispose = new Wrapper().Add();
willDispose.ThrowIfAdded();
```

the lowered code is generated as expected.

```
Wrapper willDispose = new Wrapper().Add();
try
{
    willDispose.ThrowIfAdded();
}
finally
{
    if (willDispose != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)willDispose).Dispose();
    }
}
```

While I understand *why* this is occurring, it isn't desirable. Is there any way to coerce the former initialization to compile to the latter? Ideally, it would be an attribute or form of compiler hint that would result in:

```
Wrapper willDispose = default;
try
{
    willDispose = new Wrapper().Add().ThrowIfAdded();
}
finally
{
    if (willDispose != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)willDispose).Dispose();
    }
}
```

which I would have expected the original example to compile to in the first place.

Comment: I can't see a way to *"coerce the former initialization to compile to the latter"* without some sort of post-processing. Assuming that's true, making the question unanswerable as asked, what kinds of solutions would you be willing to accept?

Comment: Clearly, you can do things *after* the chain, and those are within the try/catch. It looks like something will have to be done there, and one solution would then be to minimize what that is and make it consistent, like doing `wrapper.Complete();`. If `Add` and `ThrowIfAdded` defer execution until that call by queuing those actions, it would be disposed as you expect. Whether that fits your needs, though, is another matter.

Comment: @madreflection completely fair. I added an example to my question of what be the expected and preferred outcome. Of course you can manually write the long try/finally form yourself, but it isn't desirable.

Comment: If you're intent on putting the initialization inside of the try/catch, then what you're talking about is a change to the language, or post-processing. An AOP framework might be able to do that for you.

Comment: @madreflection that was my fear. If that's the case, it might be an item I open on the language. It is misleading as is.

Comment: You're probably going to get some pushback from them on the "misleading" characterization. The method chain yields the value of the last method call as the value of the expression. That is then the `IDisposable` managed by the `using` declaration, so that's what gets initialized outside of the try/catch. I don't think that's misleading at all.

Comment: Expecting the language to detect the first disposable expression (`new Wrapper()`) to be managed by the `using` and defer chained method calls to the body of the try/catch seems unreasonable, because it would disable the scenario with the chained expression is in fact what you want managed by `using`. Principle of least surprise.

Comment: @madreflection It isn't just about yielding the last value of the method chain however. If you have a constructor for a class that implements `IDisposable` and it throws in that constructor without any chained methods at all, you will NOT call Dispose...it never gets hit. I would say that is _absolutely_ misleading behavior.

Comment: There's guidance on that scenario out there. In that case, it needs to explicitly release those resources before it throws the exception.

Comment: Perhaps that's the answer I'm looking for in that case. When using a fluent api in conjunction with a using statement, any paths that may throw need to explicitly free resources since dispose will never be implicitly called.

Comment: IMHO the fluent part of your api should only collect parameters. Then an explicit `.Build` method (or something) should pass those parameters to a different `IDisposable` type.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman that's an interesting idea. The issue is pooling however. While this example is deliberately simple, if the fluent builder uses `ArrayPool<T>` internally to minimize allocations during construction or any other internal implementation detail that needs to be cleaned up, it would need to be done when `.Build()` is called or, if it is not, via the using statement. I'm not certain that the addition of another disposable type correctly solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there is pre-existing guidance that when an exception is thrown in a constructor, it should be explicitly handled and the resources cleaned up.

This extends to `CA2000` [analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000#how-to-fix-violations) that states:

> When constructors that are protected by only one exception handler are
> nested in the acquisition part of a using statement, a failure in the
> outer constructor can result in the object created by the nested
> constructor never being closed. In the following example, a failure in
> the StreamReader constructor can result in the FileStream object never
> being closed. CA2000 flags a violation of the rule in this case.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream("C:/myfile.txt", FileMode.Create)))
{ ... }
```

While a Fluent API throwing an exception is not explicitly either a constructor or nested constructor throwing an exception, it should be treated the same since the object will be created and mutated outside of the try/finally block.

As a result, any method that can throw must first call dispose before allowing the exception to propagate.

```
public class Wrapper : IDisposable
{
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private bool _isAdded;

    public Wrapper Add()
    {
        _isAdded = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _isDisposed = true;
        Console.WriteLine("dispose called");
    }

    public Wrapper ThrowIfAdded()
    {
        if (_isAdded)
        {
            Dispose();
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

This correctly assures that in cases where `.Added()` is called, `.ThrowIfAdded()` will dispose prior to throwing.

If `.Added()` is not called, the instance will be disposed at the end of the block as expected.